# Navigating to another view using the UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.2, uinavigationbar

I'm using the `UINavigationController` in my app and for some reason it won't allow me to switch  pages to the `third xib` called CompanyView.  It switches fine from first to second but not second third. I'm probably doing something wrong but if someone could look over my code that would be great.  I've got the button set correctly I believe. 
Here is my `.h file` for the `xib` that won't change view:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CompanyView.h"

@interface MenuView : UIViewController

-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here is my code for the `.m file`:

```
#import "MenuView.h"

@implementation MenuView

-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender {

    CompanyView * companyView = [[CompanyView alloc] init];

    companyView.title = @"Company";

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:companyView animated:YES];

    [companyView release];
}



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    
(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing your Company View this way.

```
CompanyView *companyView = [[CompanyView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CompanyView" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Hmm...its still not switching.  Is there some piece of code that I should be adding to my CompanyView.h and .m file?

Answer (score 0):

this is how i set it up:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        CategoryPresetViewController *controller = [[CategoryPresetViewController alloc] initWithPVCDelegate:avc];
        controller.title = [[factoryCategoryNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] retain];
        if (controller != nil){
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

        [controller release];
}
```

maybe it can help you

Comment: Sorry to be stupid but do you know where I could place this code?  Did you place it in your .m file anywhere special John?

Comment: What ever you press to go to the next view is where you should put everything excluding the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{` because that is for if you pressed a table row. You also will need to change `[factoryCategoryNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` to fix your needs. So controller.title = @"new title here"; also avc wont match yours, avc is activityViewController. So whatever your AVC is change it to match.

Comment: @Maple let me link you to the first tutorial i used to learn this. :] http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your patience and help John!